# GitHub Actions: access service from an 'use' statement

Tags: github, github-actions, phing

I've a small workflow for testing my app. It requires MySQL, and I use it as a service so I can specify which version I want. Tests run through `phing`, and I had to fork and customize the official image adding some commands I require.

The Phing target runs some commands, like importing data into the MySQL DB. It appears the Run phing tests step is unable to connect to the `maindb` instance.

According to docs:

> The hostname of the service container is automatically mapped to the label name. For example, if you create a service container with the label redis, the hostname of the service container is `redis`.

But the action has the following output:

```
[echo] mysql -udbuser -p --port=3306 -hmaindb dbname -e 'source ./data/sql/testing.create.sql'
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'maindb' (-3)
```

This is my workflow definition:

```yaml
name: Unit tests
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    timeout-minutes: 15

    services:
      maindb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          # Values from build/properties/default.properties
          MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
          MYSQL_USER: dbuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
    steps:
...
      - name: Run phing tests
        uses: maxxer/phing-github-action@main
        with:
            targets: runtests
```

How can I allow the phing-github-action image access the MySQL service? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the options tag in the MySQL service definition with health checks. The working definition is the following:

```yaml
    services:
      maindb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
          MYSQL_USER: dbuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
          MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
```

I also had to include `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` to make `mysqladmin` work.